# Mathworks Simulink: S-Function Builder

Tags: simulink, mex, s-function

I have a library with numerous S-function Builder blocks.

If I want to regenerate .mex files (say, on a different platform),
the standard method would be to:

- Go to every S-function builder block
- Open its S-Function Builder Wizard
- Click Build

Is there a method to automate this process, such that
every S-Function Builder block within a library (including all subsystems),
is rebuilt?

Answer (score 2):

That is possible:

```
blkNames = find_system(bdroot,'lookundermasks','all','BlockType','S-Function');
for blkIdx = 1:numel(blkNames)
  blkHandle = get_param(blkNames{blkIdx}, 'Handle');
  appdata = sfunctionwizard(blkHandle,'GetApplicationData');
  appdata = sfunctionwizard(blkHandle,'Build',appdata);
end
```

I don't have any reference or documentation, just read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168006/how-to-set-application-data-to-an-s-function-using-s-function-wizard) shortly after reading your question and verified the code is actually working.